# Making a list of tuples from a text file

Tags: python

I need to create a list of a list of tuples from a text file. The file is like this:

```
[]
[(1, 4)]
[(1, 4), (2, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 16), (3, 4)]
[(1, 4), (2, 22), (3, 24), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 32), (3, 48), (4, 16)]
[(1, 4), (2, 38), (3, 92), (4, 52), (5, 4)]
```

I need to extract each line into a list called combinations and be able to call the values inside the tuples like this:

```
combinations[1] // (1,4) <br>
combinations[1][1] // 4 <br>
```

I'm new to python, I can get each line into the list but they are of string type and a list of tuples

```
with open("combinations.txt", 'r') as f:
    combinations = f.read().splitlines()
```

What I need:

```
combinations[1] // (1,4)
combinations[1][1] // 4
```

What I get:

```
combinations[1] // '[(1, 4)]'
```

Comment: You have to convert the string representation of a tuple into an actual tuple object. One way is to use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Since these data structures can be read by python, you can do it with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
with open('combinations.txt') as f:
    tuples = list(map(ast.literal_eval, f))
```

Your tuples are now in the list `tuples`.

Good luck!